# Applying value to all members in Pandas pivot level

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a simple Pandas DataFrame `t` that looks like the following:

```
  > print t

    group_id    item_id  traitx
  0   groupA  000001-00    True
  1   groupA  000002-00    True
  2   groupA  000003-00   False
  3   groupB  000001-00    True
  4   groupC  000002-00    True
  5   groupC  000004-00    True

  > t.pivot_table(index=['groupid', 'item_id'])

                      traitx
  group_id item_id          
  groupA   000001-00    True
           000002-00    True
           000003-00   False
  groupB   000001-00    True
  groupC   000001-00    True
           000002-00    True
```

**Goal:** I need to count the total number of rows which belong to a `group_id` whose `traitx` values are all `True`.

My idea to tackle this is to somehow add a column that will show whether or not the entire group is `True` for each row, e.g.

```
    group_id    item_id  traitx  group_traitx
  0   groupA  000001-00    True         False
  1   groupA  000002-00    True         False
  2   groupA  000003-00   False         False
  3   groupB  000001-00    True         True
  4   groupC  000002-00    True         True
  5   groupC  000004-00    True         True
```

and then just do a sum of `group_traitx`.

I can calculate `group_traitx` with the following:

```
> print t.groupby('group_id')['traitx'].all()

group_id
groupA    False
groupB     True
groupC     True
Name: traitx, dtype: bool
```

However, I can't figure out how to "smear" the results back into a `group_traitx` column in my original DataFrame.

Disclaimer - I just started using Pandas yesterday, so this may not be the best way to achieve my original goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df= t.pivot_table(index=['group_id', 'item_id'])
df['group_traitx'] = df.groupby(level=0)['traitx'].transform('all')
print (df)
                    traitx  group_traitx
group_id item_id                        
groupA   000001-00    True         False
         000002-00    True         False
         000003-00   False         False
groupB   000001-00    True          True
groupC   000002-00    True          True
         000004-00    True          True

print (df['group_traitx'].sum())
3
```

New column is not necessary:

```
print (df.groupby(level=0)['traitx'].transform('all').sum())
3
```

And if need only all `True` groups use [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df= t.pivot_table(index=['group_id', 'item_id'])
print (df.groupby(level=0)['traitx'].filter('all'))

group_id  item_id  
groupB    000001-00    True
groupC    000002-00    True
          000004-00    True
Name: traitx, dtype: bool

print (df.groupby(level=0)['traitx'].filter('all').sum())
3
```

EDIT:

If duplicates in `group_id` and `item_id` pairs:

```
#added duplicates
print (t)
  group_id    item_id  traitx
0   groupA  000001-00    True
1   groupA  000001-00    True
2   groupA  000001-00   False
3   groupB  000001-00    True
4   groupC  000002-00    True
5   groupC  000004-00    True

#pivot_table is not necessary for new column of original df
t['group_traitx'] = t.groupby(['group_id', 'item_id'])['traitx'].transform('all')
print (t)
  group_id    item_id  traitx  group_traitx
0   groupA  000001-00    True         False
1   groupA  000001-00    True         False
2   groupA  000001-00   False         False
3   groupB  000001-00    True          True
4   groupC  000002-00    True          True
5   groupC  000004-00    True          True
```

If need working with aggregate df (unique pairs `group_id` with `item_id`):
`pivot_table` use default aggregate function `mean`, but need aggregate by  [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html):

```
print (t.pivot_table(index=['group_id', 'item_id']))
                      traitx
group_id item_id            
groupA   000001-00  0.666667
groupB   000001-00  1.000000
groupC   000002-00  1.000000
         000004-00  1.000000

df = t.pivot_table(index=['group_id', 'item_id'], aggfunc='all')
df['group_traitx'] = df.groupby(level=0)['traitx'].transform('all')
print (df)
                    traitx  group_traitx
group_id item_id                        
groupA   000001-00   False         False
groupB   000001-00    True          True
groupC   000002-00    True          True
         000004-00    True          True
```

Comment: Amazing! I had to groupby(level=1), but otherwise this works perfectly.  The documentation for transform() is a little opaque. Do you have any pointers on where I can see list of acceptable function names to pass in, or any comprehensive examples?

Comment: You can use a lot of functions - see [list](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id32).